# Extracting Walls from Image in OpenCv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I have the following image of a maze:

Input:

[image]

The walls are white and the path is black. How can I extract one of the walls in a separate image in opencv?

This is the output I want

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Can you add a second picture showing the result you expect  please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the concept of [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) for this problem.

In your input image notice how the 'walls' are distinct and are neighbored by black pixels (path). When you initialize the algorithm at any one pixel within this 'wall' they will be separated from the rest of the image.

**Code:**

```
path = r'C:\Users\Desktop'
filename = 'input.png'

img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, filename))
cv2.imshow('Original', img)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('thresh1', thresh)
```

[image]

```
im_floodfill = thresh.copy()

h, w = thresh.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)

cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255)
cv2.imshow('im_floodfill', im_floodfill)
```

[image]

```
cv2.imshow('fin', cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill) + thresh))
```

[image]

There is another example detailing this function on [THIS POST](https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/)